# scipy install error

Tags: python, windows, scipy

I use activestate python 2.7.10 32bit on Windows 10 64bit.
I installed `numpy` and it worked but `scipy` gives me a headache.

I tried to pypm install `scipy` following https://code.activestate.com/pypm/scipy/
but it gives CRC check error.

When I pip install `scipy`, it gives the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking scipy
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py) egg_info for package scipy

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*_subr_*.f' found under directory 'scipy\linalg\src\id_dist\src'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks\env'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks\results'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks\html'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks\scipy'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scipy\special\tests\data\boost'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scipy\special\tests\data\gsl'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source\generated'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*\__pycache__'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in []
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in []
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:564: UserWarning: Specified path /home/apy/atlas/lib is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:564: UserWarning: Specified path /home/apy/atlas/include is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1419: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1422: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py", line 262, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py", line 182, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python2.7.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kwan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_KWan\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip-7fm9d5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in []

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

  libraries lapack not found in []

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:564: UserWarning: Specified path /home/apy/atlas/lib is invalid.

  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)

C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:564: UserWarning: Specified path /home/apy/atlas/include is invalid.

  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)

C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1419: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1422: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

Running from scipy source directory.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py", line 265, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py", line 262, in setup_package

    setup(**metadata)

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    config = configuration()

  File "c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy\setup.py", line 182, in configuration

    config.add_subpackage('scipy')

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage

    caller_level = 2)

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage

    caller_level = caller_level + 1)

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)

  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration

    config.add_subpackage('linalg')

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage

    caller_level = 2)

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage

    caller_level = caller_level + 1)

  File "C:\Users\KWan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)

  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration

    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')

numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python2.7.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kwan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_KWan\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip-7fm9d5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\kwan\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_KWan\scipy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\KWan\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: Why not install one of the Python distributions that come with scipy out of the box? http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: That is also an option. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a Python distribution which comes with scipy you can download the binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). 
For your 32 bit, python 2.7 you need: **scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl**

This is a wheel package, which you can install with:

```
pip install scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Comment: Thx Maecky for your answer. I get the message saying that lit looks like a filename but does not exist. Where Could I find whl file and which directory should it go?

Comment: You download the *.whl to your computer (no matter where, just remeber the directory). pip.exe is located in you Python directory. On my computer it is on C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe - you simply execute it, like I mentioned in my answer... pip.exe install C:\pathToYourDownload\scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. It worked. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome, please select the answer as correct one. This indicates, that your Problem is solved.

Comment: Maecky. I want to do what you told me but this is my fiirst time to use stackoveflow so cannot find set the answer as correct.